# Is it possible to have meaningful labels in the Custom Animation pane?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

The Custom Animation panel shows items with labels such as "Rectangle 37", "Group 59", etc., which are meaningless and hard to associate with the items on the slide.

Is there a way to name these items with meaningful labels that can be assigned by the user?

I am using PowerPoint 2010, but I think my question would apply to earlier versions as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instructions (*taken from [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_5904252_rename-powerpoint-objects-animation.html)*)

> 1. Launch Microsoft PowerPoint and open the presentation you wish to edit.
> 2. Click the "Home" tab located at the top left corner, and click "Select" under the "Editing" menu located in the top right corner. (Note: on Mac look for "Arrange", then choose "Selection Pane...".)
> 3. Click the "Selection Pane," the third option from the drop-down menu. A pane will appear on the right side of the screen, displaying
>      all the objects in the slide.
> 4. Click on the object names to rename the objects. You may double-click and type in the name and press the "Enter" key to rename
>      the objects.